# Updating offers based on selected products

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I have some nokia mobile models with some offers. There are two objects, one for nokia models with price, another one for offers.

For example I have offers for these two models:

"brandname": "Nokia"
"model":"Lumia"
"submodel": "Lumia 735 TS"

"brandname": "Nokia"
"model":"Lumia"
"submodel": "Lumia 830"

My expectation is that whenever a checkbox is checked, I need to update the offer object. If there are any offers for the checked mobile model, one dropdown should appear and it will show the offer message.

For example: Lumia 735 TS is checked in the checkbox list. It has offer in the offer list, so one dropdown should come after that checkbox list which should show "Offer_message":"1000rs off" offer message. If I uncheck the model, that dropdown should not show.

Here Lumia 735 TS and Lumia 510 are both checked in my demo, so it should show two offer messages in the dropdown list.
I have added working code but I need to reduce lines.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrlFun);
MyCtrlFun.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter', '$timeout','$http'];
function MyCtrlFun($scope, $filter, $timeout,$http) {

//****** Selected List****
$scope.selectedlist = ["Lumia 735 TS", "Lumia 510"];

$scope.checkbox_model = [];
$scope.checkbox_list = [];

$scope.offers = [];
$scope.phones = [];

$scope.submitModel = [];
var submodel = [];
var models = {};
var brandname = {};
$scope.finalOutput = {
  city:null,
    Storename : null,
    Offerid : null,
    Offer_price : null,
    Total_price : null,
    Sub_Total_price : null,
    Categories : []
}

 
$scope.finalOutput_withNullFilter = {};

   
  
$scope.checkItems = function(){
  $scope.checkbox_list = [];
  $scope.selectedlist = new Array();
$scope.flag=true;
  for(var item in $scope.checkbox_model){
  if($scope.checkbox_model[item].isChecked)
    {
    $scope.flag=false;
      $scope.selectedlist.push($scope.checkbox_model[item].name);
      $scope.checkbox_list.push($scope.checkbox_model[item]);
    }

    
    
  }
      
  $scope.checkbox_list.push({offer_id : $scope.selected_offer_id});
  //alert(Storename)
  /*var m = priceChangeToOffer($scope.selected_offer_id);
  
  if(!isNaN(m)){
   $scope.total_price =$scope.total_price-parseInt(m);
    }*/
  $scope.checkbox_list.push({sub_total : $scope.sub_total});
  checkWithSeletedModel();
  
  $scope.finalOutput.city=$scope.phones[0].city;
  
  $scope.finalOutput_withNullFilter = $scope.finalOutput;
  
  if($scope.finalOutput.Storename==null)
  {
   $scope.finalOutput.Storename = $scope.phones[0].Storename;
  }
  
  if($scope.selected_item==null)
  {
      delete $scope.finalOutput.Offerid;
  }
  else{
      $scope.finalOutput.Offerid = $scope.selected_item;
  }
  
  if($scope.Offer_price==0)
  {
    delete $scope.finalOutput.Offer_price;  
  }
  else{
      $scope.finalOutput.Offer_price = $scope.Offer_price;
  }
  
  $scope.finalOutput.Sub_Total_price = $scope.sub_total;
  $scope.finalOutput.Total_price= $scope.total_price;
  if($scope.flag==true)
   {alert("Select one");
   }else{
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.finalOutput));
   }
   
  /*if($scope.finalOutput.Total_price<=0 && $scope.finalOutput.Sub_Total_price==0){
     
  }
  else{
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.finalOutput));
 }*/
  
  //****** redefine finalOutput after Submit data to server
  $scope.finalOutput = {
      city:null,
      Storename : null,
      Offerid : null,
      Offer_price : null,
      Total_price : null,
      Sub_Total_price : null,
      Categories : []
  }
}

$scope.selectedbrand = 'Nokia';
$scope.submodel ='Lumia';
$scope.phones = [{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56a9c44f40d0275643cfc04e"
    },
    "default": [],
    "Categories": [
        {
            "models": [
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "Not available",
                            "name": "Lumia 735 TS"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "8100",
                            "name": "Lumia 510"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "9900",
                            "name": "Lumia 830"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Lumia"
                },
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "10000",
                            "name": "Asha 230"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "11999",
                            "name": "Asha Asn01"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Asha"
                }
            ],
            "brandname": "Nokia",
            "id": "986745"
        },
        {
            "models": [
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "5000",
                            "name": "Trend 840"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "6999",
                            "name": "A5"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Galaxy"
                },
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "12000",
                            "name": "Asha 230"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Asha"
                }
            ],
            "brandname": "Samsung",
            "id": "144745"
        }
    ],
    "Storename": "Zig Zag Mobiles",
 "Shopid":"asdef1234",
  "city":"bengaluru",
    "__v": 0
}
 
];

$scope.offers = [
 {
  id: "as23456",
  "Storename": "Zig Zag Mobiles",
  "Shopid":"asdef1234",
        "Offer_message":"1000rs off",
  "Categories": [
        {
            "models": [
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "1000",
                            "name": "Lumia 735 TS"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Lumia"
                }
            ],
            "brandname": "Nokia",
            "id": "986745"
        }
    ],  
      
    },{
  id: "de34575",
        "Storename": "Zig Zag Mobiles",
  "Shopid":"asdef1234",
        "Offer_message":"500rs off",
  "Categories": [
        {
            "models": [
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "500",
                            "name": "Lumia 830"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Lumia"
                }
            ],
            "brandname": "Nokia",
            "id": "345645"
        }
    ],         
      
    },
 {
  id: "ert25675",
        "Storename": "Zig Zag Mobiles",
  "Shopid":"asdef1234",
        "Offer_message":"100 Flat",
  "Categories": [
        {
            "models": [
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "100",
                            "name": "Asha 230"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Asha"
                }
            ],
            "brandname": "Samsung",
            "id": "345645"
        }
    ],         
      
    }
];
        
   /*$http.get('http://19.168.1.4/shop1/').success(function(data, status, response) 
        {
  $scope.phones =data;
  });*/
//----------------------------Our Shop Offers----------------------------------------
/*$http.get('http://19.168.1.4/shop1/').success(function(response,data) 
{
    $scope.phones =[data];
    checkWithSeletedModel();
}).error(function(error, status){
    alert("got error"+status);
});
  
$http.get('http://19.168.1.4/offers/').success(function(data, status, response) 
{
    $scope.offers =data;
}).error(function(error, status){
    alert("got error"+status);
});*/

  $scope.offerSelectedList = [];
  $scope.total_price = 0, $scope.sub_total=0, $scope.Offer_price=0, $scope.selected_item=null;
  $scope.changeItemStateFun = function(checkbox_value){
      $scope.selected_item=null;
      $scope.Offer_price=0;
      
    $timeout(function(){
        if(checkbox_value.isChecked){

          if(!isNaN(checkbox_value.price)){
            $scope.total_price =$scope.total_price+parseInt(checkbox_value.price);
            }

          var checked_offer = getOffer([checkbox_value]);

                    if(checked_offer!=false){
              $scope.offerSelectedList.push(checked_offer);
              //alert(checked_offer.Categories[0].models[0].submodel[0].name);
            }
        }else{
          if(!isNaN(checkbox_value.price)){
                    $scope.total_price = $scope.total_price-parseInt(checkbox_value.price);
            }

            var checked_offer = getOffer([checkbox_value]);
          if(checked_offer!=false){
              var tempOfferList = [];
              for(var i in $scope.offerSelectedList){
                 if($scope.offerSelectedList[i].id!=checked_offer.id){
                    tempOfferList.push($scope.offerSelectedList[i]);
                 }
              }
              $scope.offerSelectedList = tempOfferList;
            }
        }

        if($scope.offerSelectedList.length==0){
            $scope.Offer_price = 0;
            $scope.sub_total = $scope.total_price;
        }
        else{
          $scope.Offer_price = $scope.offerSelectedList[0].Categories[0].models[0].submodel[0].price;
          $scope.sub_total = $scope.total_price-$scope.Offer_price;
          $scope.selected_item = $scope.offerSelectedList[0].id;
        }

        $scope.finalOutput.Total_price = $scope.total_price;
    });
  }
  
  $scope.selected_offer_id = null;
  $scope.submit_offer = {};
  $scope.offerSeleted = function(offer){
      
      $scope.selected_item = null;
      $scope.Offer_price =0;
      
    $scope.selected_offer_id = offer;
    var m = priceChangeToOffer($scope.selected_offer_id);
    
    if(!isNaN(m.Offer_price)){
        
      $scope.Offer_price = parseInt(m.Offer_price);
      $scope.sub_total =$scope.total_price-$scope.Offer_price;
      }
      
    $scope.selected_item=m.Offerid;
    $scope.Offer_price = m.Offer_price;
    
    $scope.finalOutput.Storename = m.Storename;
    $scope.finalOutput.Offerid = m.Offerid;
    $scope.finalOutput.Offer_price = m.Offer_price;
    $scope.finalOutput.Total_price = $scope.total_price;
    $scope.finalOutput.Sub_Total_price = $scope.sub_total;
    
  }
  
  function getOffer(checkedItem){
   for(var i=0; i<checkedItem.length; i++){
    
     for(var j=0; j<$scope.offers.length; j++){
       for(var k=0;k<$scope.offers[j].Categories.length; k++){
         for(var m=0; m<$scope.offers[j].Categories[k].models.length; m++){
           for(var n=0; n<$scope.offers[j].Categories[k].models[m].submodel.length; n++){
               if($scope.offers[j].Categories[k].models[m].submodel[n].name==checkedItem[i].name){
                  
                    return $scope.offers[j];
                    }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    return false;
  }
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //delete below line
  checkWithSeletedModel();
  function checkWithSeletedModel(){
  
  $scope.finalOutput.Categories = [];
  $scope.submitModel = [];
 submodel = [];
 models = {};
 brandname = {};
  $scope.offerSelectedList = [];
  $scope.total_price = 0;
  
  $scope.checkbox_model = [];

  for(var i=0; i<$scope.phones.length; i++){
   for(var j=0; j<$scope.phones[i].Categories.length; j++){
     
      if($scope.phones[i].Categories[j].brandname==$scope.selectedbrand){
      
      brandname = {
         id : $scope.phones[i].Categories[j].id,
          brandname : $scope.phones[i].Categories[j].brandname,
          models : []
        };
       models = {};
      for(var k=0; k<$scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models.length; k++){
         if($scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].name==$scope.submodel){    
       models = {
           name : $scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].name,
            submodel : []
          }
          
        for(var m=0; m<$scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel.length; m++){

    var verifyIsCheck = false;
    if($scope.selectedlist.length>0){
    verifyIsCheck=verifyIsChecked($scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel[m].name);
     }
         if(verifyIsCheck==true){
           models.submodel.push({name : $scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel[m].name, price:($scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel[m].price=='Not available'?null:$scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel[m].price)});
            //models.submodel
         }
         
         var obj1 = {isChecked :verifyIsCheck, name : $scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel[m].name, price:$scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel[m].price};
            
           //$scope.changeItemStateFun(obj1);
            var checkedOffer = getOffer([obj1]);
            if(checkedOffer!=false && verifyIsCheck==true){
             $scope.offerSelectedList.push(checkedOffer); 
              
            }
            if(verifyIsCheck==true && !isNaN(obj1.price)){
             $scope.total_price = $scope.total_price+parseInt(obj1.price);
              }
            
            $scope.checkbox_model.push(obj1);
          }
          }
      }
      brandname.models.push(models);
      $scope.submitModel.push(brandname);
      }
   }
}

$scope.finalOutput.Categories.push($scope.submitModel);
}


  function verifyIsChecked(submodel_name){
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.selectedlist.length; i++){
   if($scope.selectedlist[i]==submodel_name){
      
         return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  //********** For total sum checked model and change according to offer
 function priceChangeToOffer(offer_id){
 
    for(var j=0; j<$scope.offers.length; j++){
    
      if(offer_id!=$scope.offers[j].id)
         continue;
       
        for(var k=0;k<$scope.offers[j].Categories.length; k++){
         for(var m=0; m<$scope.offers[j].Categories[k].models.length; m++){
           for(var n=0; n<$scope.offers[j].Categories[k].models[m].submodel.length; n++){
             var offer_obj = {
               Storename : $scope.offers[j].Storename,
        Offerid :  $scope.offers[j].id,
        Offer_price : $scope.offers[j].Categories[k].models[m].submodel[0].price
              };
              return offer_obj;
            }
          }
        }
      }
 }  

$scope.sub_total = $scope.total_price;
$scope.finalOutput.Total_price = $scope.total_price;
$scope.finalOutput.Sub_Total_price = $scope.sub_total;

}


myApp.filter("removespace", function(){
   return function(input){
     return input.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "_")
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in phones">
          <div ng-repeat="cat in item.Categories" ng-show="cat.brandname==selectedbrand">
            <h2><b>{{ cat.brandname }}</b></h2>
              <div ng-repeat="models in cat.models" ng-show="models.name==submodel">
                <h3>
                  <b>{{models.name}}</b>
                </h3>
                <div ng-repeat="submodels in models.submodel">
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox_model[$index].isChecked" ng-change="changeItemStateFun(checkbox_model[$index])"/>{{ submodels.name }}

                </div><br/><br/>
              
                
                <div><b>Total Price : {{total_price}}</b><br/></div>
                <div ng-show="Offer_price!=0"><b>Offer Price : {{Offer_price}}</b></div>
                <div><b>Sub Total = {{sub_total}}</b><br/></div>
                <select ng-show="offerSelectedList.length>0" ng-model="selected_item" ng-options="offer.id as offer.Offer_message for offer in offerSelectedList" ng-change="offerSeleted(selected_item)">
                  <option>select offer</option>
                </select>
                
                <!--<select  ng-show="offerSelectedList.length>0" ng-model="selected_item" ng-change="offerSeleted(selected_item)">
                    <option ng-repeat="offer in offerSelectedList" value="{{offer.id}}">{{offer.Offer_message}} {{offer.id}}</option>
                </select>-->


              </div>
          </div>



      <button ng-click="checkItems()">Do</button>
      </div>  
      </div>
```

Comment: @IvanModric nice of you to edit the code, but all parts of the code are up for review, **including indentation**.

Comment: what can i do sir @ Ivan Modric  .if possible can you pls use your code and get this done but don't change that two objects

Comment: @Pimgd I appreciate the criticism. But having **neat** code is usually a good start.

Comment: @IvanModric all the more reason for you to write a review on that subject. For other reviewers, **if you need to look at a well formatted version, revision 5 has fixed formatting**.

Comment: Short advice: avoid `$scope`, use `controllerAs` feature.

Comment: can you please help me out @elclanrs